# MSMQ raising IOException intermittently when using .NET

Tags: .net, msmq, ioexception

Having an intermittent issue with MSMQ where it generates `System.IO.IOException` when sending to queue. There isn't any information on this info I can find so not sure why it could be happening (MSDN documentation doesn't even list this an issue). As said it is intermittent so debugging it is hard and does not occur on dev environment (only in QA)

Stack Trace:

```
   at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.FromSourceBatch(System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters, System.String[])
   at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.System.CodeDom.Compiler.ICodeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromSourceBatch(System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters, System.String[])
   at System.Xml.Serialization.Compiler.Compile(System.Reflection.Assembly, System.String, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializerCompilerParameters, System.Security.Policy.Evidence)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.GenerateAssembly(System.Xml.Serialization.XmlMapping[], System.Type[], System.String, System.Security.Policy.Evidence, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializerCompilerParameters, System.Reflection.Assembly, System.Collections.Hashtable)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly..ctor(System.Xml.Serialization.XmlMapping[], System.Type[], System.String, System.String, System.Security.Policy.Evidence)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(System.Type, System.String)
   at System.Messaging.XmlMessageFormatter.Write(System.Messaging.Message, System.Object)
   at System.Messaging.Message.AdjustToSend()
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.SendInternal(System.Object, System.Messaging.MessageQueueTransaction, System.Messaging.MessageQueueTransactionType)
   at Test.MSMQWrite.WriteMessageInternal(System.String, System.Object, Boolean)
   at Test.Program.Main(System.String[])
```

Code for WriteMessageInternal:

```
private static void WriteMessageInternal(string queueName, object data)
{            
    using (var queue = new MessageQueue(queueName, false, false, QueueAccessMode.Send))
    {                
        queue.Send(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try logging what the actual object type is when you fail so that no unintended type is showing up as "object"? Seems something has trouble being serialized, and it sounds like something that shouldn't be random unless the types passed in are.

Comment: The only other "randomness generator" I could think of would be if something is stopping file writes. Did you try to disable the antivirus temporarily? Does QA have another antivirus than you do?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I can confirm that no unintended type is showing up so I doubt it is serialisation. I think you are closer with the stopping fire writes - no AV on the box though that could be the cause.

Comment: Are you filling up the queue by any chance do you have slower/more infrequent writes than reads?

Comment: Queue not being filled, at most we have 2 or 3 messages in the queue and they are all <0.5kb.

Comment: The only thing causing an IOException in Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.FromSourceBatch that I can see is writing a file to disk, most likely temp storage. Intermittent failures on that seems odd since there's no antivirus stopping it.